# Grouping employee time In and Out in a single record with hours in office and outside office in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following set of sample data which depicts a user's attendance for a particular day. What I want to achieve is to display the data of the user on a single record. 
For example:

```
123 | Sedora Choli | 08:12 | 08:36 | Hours worked 
123 | Sedora Choli | 09:32 | 09:36 | Hours worked
```

How can I handle the tailgating issue in the records ? I want to retrieve the number of hours of being outside office also.

```
UserID| Name|        IOType|    timeIn|                  timeOut
123|    Sedora Choli|0|         2019-07-19 08:12:03.000  NULL
123|    Sedora Choli|1|         NULL                   | 2019-07-19 08:36:44.000
123|    Sedora Choli|0|         2019-07-19 09:32:29.000| NULL
123|    Sedora Choli|0|         2019-07-19 09:32:38.000| NULL
123|    Sedora Choli|1|         NULL|                    2019-07-19 09:34:44.000
123|    Sedora Choli|0|         2019-07-19 09:46:30.000| NULL
123|    Sedora Choli|1|         NULL|                    2019-07-19 09:48:45.000
123|    Sedora Choli|0|         2019-07-19 09:49:42.000| NULL
123|    Sedora Choli|1|         NULL|                    2019-07-19 11:16:12.000
123|    Sedora Choli|0|         2019-07-19 11:23:52.000| NULL
123|    Sedora Choli|1|         NULL|                    2019-07-19 12:29:34.000
123|    Sedora Choli|0|         2019-07-19 12:45:57.000| NULL
123|    Sedora Choli|1|         NULL|                    2019-07-19 12:58:23.000
123|    Sedora Choli|0|         2019-07-19 13:00:12.000| NULL
123|    Sedora Choli|0|         2019-07-19 13:20:28.000| NULL
123|    Sedora Choli|1|         NULL                   | 2019-07-19 17:55:45.000
```

Can someone please help to achieve this in sql ?

Comment: Your statement is that you want the data in a single record for a given user.  Then you show an example of two rows for a single user.  That is confusing.

Comment: Is it possible to have missing entries? E.g. two consecutive ins or outs?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to match ins and outs.  First, eliminate adjacent duplicates by only keeping records where the in/out flag differs from the previous row.  Then use `lead()` to get the next record and filter again:

```
select userid, name, timein, timeout,
       datediff(minute, timein, timeout) / 60.0 as hours_worked
from (select t.*,
             lead(timeout) over (partition by userid order by coalesce(timein, timeout)) as timeout
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(iotype) over (partition by userid order by coalesce(timein, timeout)) as prev_iotype
            from t
           ) t
      where prev_iotype is null or prev_iotype <> iotype
     ) t
where iotype = 0;
```

Comment: What if I want to get the hours outside of office also?

Comment: @crazydev . . . This answers the question that you have asked here.  If you have a different question, then ask as a *new* question.